# Android library dependency

Tags: android

Android library scenario.

A - is the main Libray has Activities and other classes

B - is a library that depends on A (A is dependency of B)  and B extends/subclasses an Activity of A

C - An app that need A and B both.

Question: 
Is it sufficient to add only B as dependency of C. Because B has dependency on A and therefore classes of A will be automatically resolve for C ?

Comment: https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/dependency_management.html   note link for " transitive dependency mgmt"  is exactly what ur question entails

Comment: Yes because in A library is inherited B library. So you just add B library only.

Answer (score 0):

Yes as per the Multilevel inheritance in java, library dependencies also follow that rule. So, it is sufficient to add B to the project C which already contains A. SO, in your project you can use both the classes of A and B , by importing B only.

Answer (score 0):

Having dependency "B" is enough as it already has dependency "A" included inside.. Lets take a example

'com.github.afollestad.material-dialogs:core:0.8.5.1@aar' is a dependency that i have used in one of my apps and notice that i haven't included any other dependency that is required by( depends upon ) the above mentioned dependency 
[image: Android studio dependency list]

Now if you look at the dependencies that 'com.github.afollestad.material-dialogs:core:0.8.5.1@aar' depends upon

[image: Dependencies of the above mentioned library]

Notice that i haven't included any of the dependencies of the library on the dependency list on my app.. hope this explains and answers your question